# Creating share button to share only on specific FB page

Tags: javascript, facebook-social-plugins

Is it possible to create share button for sharing posts only on FB page of the website?

Let's say that user is on some website, and wants to share blog post. User clicks on share button, and that post is shared on facebook page of that website?

So here, [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/) you click on share button, and that link is shared on Stackoverflow's facebook page.

Comment: I have literally no idea what your asking here?

Comment: @Liam Let's say that you are on Stackoverlow's blog post (etc https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/28/evaluating-options-amazons-hq2-using-stack-overflow-data/). You click on share button and that post is shared to Facebook page of Stackoverlow (not your profile or other page)

Comment: hat have you tried so far?

Comment: So you want to share onto **your** (the web sites) facebook page whenever someone clicks a button?

Comment: @liam That's right. I know it sounds stupid, but hey, that's what client wants.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Use the Share Dialog, it offers the option to "Share on a Page you Manage".

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. Because other users needs to share post on my fb page. They don't have my page under "pages they manage"

Comment: that is not possible, you can test all the options of the share dialog - there is a button for it in the docs.